# Node.js: breakpoints in setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, v8

I am debugging a node.js (Node version 6.2.1) program with `setInterval()` in it. The code is very simple:

```
const log = console.log;

let cnt = 0;
const inc = () => {
    const beforeDebug = Date.now();
    log('Before debug time', beforeDebug);

    debugger;

    const afterDebug = Date.now();
    log('After debug time', Date.now());

    log('Time spent in debug', afterDebug - beforeDebug);
    log(`[${cnt++}]`);
};
setInterval(inc, 1000);
```

```

The strange behaviour that I observe is that the pauses between `setInterval()` callback execution will depend on how much time I spend in a breakpoint. For example, if I stay in 'debugger' line for 10 seconds and then resume, I will see the next number only in 10 seconds **after** I resumed.

I checked this behaviour with command line node debugger and node-inspector.

**[UPDATE] (added timestamps to code)**
Here's an extracted lines of debug session in command line:

```
Debugger listening on port 5858
connecting to 127.0.0.1:5858 ... ok

< Before debug time 1467952218915
< After debug time 1467952235018
< Time spent in debug 16103

< Before debug time 1467952252123
```

Basically the time difference between the executions of the callback in the last section is 17105 which is almost exactly `<time-in-debug> + <interval-value>`

This issue doesn't have a significant practical impact, but I would love to understand the mechanism of timer underneath. Why it behaves in such weird way?

Comment: But then the next one should be fired 500ms after you resume debug. But it looks like it fires <time-you-spent-in-breakpoint> + 500. Actually I'll add some timestamps to the code, might be a good idea.

Comment: I see now, it sounds weird. Not reproducible in chrome though. A node version might be helpful.

Comment: Added node version to the question: v.6.2.1 also added timestamps to the code.

Comment: What if you stay much longer, like a minute? And what if you immediately step through it?

Comment: Still holds. Just tried with a minute time and it took one more minute to wait 'till the next hit. When you skip it also holds, the timeout fires normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that the time used to determine when to trigger callbacks is [cached](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6f75b6672ca08c2bc3bf5fe14abb1a9648601e28/lib/timers.js#L162) and can get out of sync with a callback's actual [insertion time](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6f75b6672ca08c2bc3bf5fe14abb1a9648601e28/lib/timers.js#L123).

#### How is this possible?

To understand why this happens, it helps to have an idea of how node's timers are implemented (which is very well documented [in the source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6f75b6672ca08c2bc3bf5fe14abb1a9648601e28/lib/timers.js)). Here, all we need to remember is that:

- Callbacks are stored in a map keyed by timeout. For example, when you run `setTimeout(foo, 10)`, then `foo` will be added to a list of all callbacks with timeout `10`.
- Callbacks keep track of the time at which they were inserted. We'll refer to it as `insertionTime` to keep things simple (it's actually `timer._idleStart` in the source).
- When a timeout kicks in, node records the current time (`now`) and runs the timeout's callbacks in sequence until either no callbacks are left or a callback's insertion time is such that [`now - insertionTime < timeout`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6f75b6672ca08c2bc3bf5fe14abb1a9648601e28/lib/timers.js#L171). In that last case, node will [*delay the next wakeup of this timeout*](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6f75b6672ca08c2bc3bf5fe14abb1a9648601e28/lib/timers.js#L172) until `timeout - (now - insertionTime)`.

In your case, here is what happens:

1. `t=0`, `inc` is inserted in a callback list with `insertionTime=0`.
2. `t=1000`, the timeout wakes up, records `now=1000`, and runs `inc`.
3. `t=3000` (or however long you are debugging for), `inc` completes and gets [reinserted in the callback list](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6f75b6672ca08c2bc3bf5fe14abb1a9648601e28/lib/timers.js#L428) (since you are using `setInterval`), this time with `insertionTime=3000`.
4. `t=3000`, node keeps going through the list of callbacks and finds the newly inserted callback. It computes `now - insertionTime = -2000` which is smaller than `timeout` (because `now` is still equal to `1000`!). It therefore schedules the next callback execution `3000 = 1000 - (-2000)` milliseconds later.
5. `t=6000`, the timeout wakes up again, records `now=6000`, and runs `inc`.
6. ...

You can get some visibility on timer internals by running your program with `NODE_DEBUG=timer`:

```
$ NODE_DEBUG=timer node setinterval.js
TIMER 98831: no 1000 list was found in insert, creating a new one
TIMER 98831: timeout callback 1000
TIMER 98831: now: 1067
inc
TIMER 98831: 1000 list wait because diff is -2000
TIMER 98831: timeout callback 1000


TIMER 98831: now: 6072
inc
TIMER 98831: 1000 list wait because diff is -2000
...
```

As far as I can tell, this looks like a bug in node. I don't see when it would make sense to have a negative `diff` above.

#### What can we do about it?

You seem to be asking this more out of curiosity, but in case you ever need to prevent this added delay, you can work around it by making sure that you have at least one other callback for the same timeout. This will force an update to `now`.

```
function f() {
  var end = Date.now() + 2000;
  while (Date.now() < end); // 2 second busy loop.
  console.log('f: ' + Date.now());
}
setInterval(f, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
  setInterval(function () {}, 1000);
}, 10); // Small delay to make sure they don't run in the same wakeup.
```

If we only add `f`, it would end up running every 5 seconds. However, if we also register the (empty) second callback, `f` will correctly run every 3 seconds!

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed answers and links to the node source! Too bad I just have one upvote!

Comment: @Juriy "Too bad I just have one upvote" --- you can add a bounty ;-P

Answer (score 0):

<del>Node.js runs your code in one single thread. 
When you pause the execution, the consequential callback will also be delayed until you resume.</del>

Here is an alternative example without employing debugger

```
var blockUntil = Date.now() + 7000;

function f() {
    console.log('Before: ', Date.now())
    while (Date.now() < blockUntil); // busy loop
    console.log(' After: ', Date.now())
}

setInterval(f, 1000);
```

And I can confirm it can be reproduced without debugger.

```
Before:  1467966150871
 After:  1467966156847
Before:  1467966163851
 After:  1467966163851
Before:  1467966164856
 After:  1467966164856
Before:  1467966165859
 After:  1467966165859
Before:  1467966166864
 After:  1467966166864
```

Comment: Please read the description carefully, the execution is delayed not only for the time of debugging but also when the breakpoint is released.

Comment: You are right, busy loop gives the same results. Time between first 'After' and the next 'Before' is 7004 millis (6000 millis for a busy loop + 1000 millis for setInterval)